# Default save type for email in outlook 2003

Tags: email, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2003

How / Where do I set the default email save type for an email using Outlook 2003?

Right now, it's set to `.oft`, and I'd like it to be `.msg`

Thanks!

Comment: Great question, but everything I'm reading says you can't do it.  The best alternative is to drag the e-mail out of Outlook and into a folder in Windows Explorer.  That will automatically save it as a .MSG in that folder.

Comment: I come up with the same answers. But I'm not happy with it. There must be a way. I checked on more than one computer. They all have the same list of save types, however, one was .oft, and another was .doc. The fact that they are set differently suggest (to me), that there should be a way.

Comment: Hmm... Try comparing `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office` on the two machines.  See what values don't match up.

Comment: In particular, try seeing if you can find a value called "DefaultFormat" for Outlook on the one that is saving differently.  That is the value used by Excel and Word.